# METAscii Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, quine

**Introduction**

Here at code colf SE, we appear to love meta-problems. Here, I've tried to compose a meta-problem that's an interesting, not-straightforward challenge.

**Challenge**

The answer code is allowed to read its own source code, but not allowed to use external resources.

All characters should be 5-lines tall. Characters used in the ascii representation are also not important, though they must be visible. Each visible character in the output will count as one byte, regardless of cheaty byte-values. Spaces used in the code are necessary, and may be only one byte wide if desired.

Lowest Byte Count ***of the output*** wins. Output must exist and include at least 1 visible byte.

Example Input and Output

**Input:**

For an example code:

```
print theanswer
```

One possible answer is:

**Output:**

```
PPPP  RRRR  III N   N TTTTTT  TTTTTT H  H EEEE   AA  N   N  SSS  W     W EEEE RRRR 
P   P R   R  I  NN  N   TT      TT   H  H E     A  A NN  N S     W     W E    R   R
PPPP  RRRR   I  N N N   TT      TT   HHHH EEE   AAAA N N N  SSS  W  W  W EEE  RRRR 
P     R R    I  N  NN   TT      TT   H  H E     A  A N  NN     S  W W W  E    R R  
P     R  RR III N   N   TT      TT   H  H EEEE  A  A N   N SSSS    W W   EEEE R  RR
```

The alphabet used should consist of the following ***patterns***, the characters used are not important:
:

```
 AA  BBBB   CCC DDD  EEEE FFFF  GGG  H  H III     J K  K L    M   M N   N  OOO  PPPP   QQQ   RRRR   SSS  TTTTTT U   U V     V W     W X   X Y   Y ZZZZZ
A  A B   B C    D  D E    F    G     H  H  I      J K K  L    MM MM NN  N O   O P   P Q   Q  R   R S       TT   U   U V     V W     W  X X   Y Y     Z 
AAAA BBBB  C    D  D EEE  FFF  G  GG HHHH  I      J KK   L    M M M N N N O   O PPPP  Q   Q  RRRR   SSS    TT   U   U  V   V  W  W  W   X     Y     Z  
A  A B   B C    D  D E    F    G   G H  H  I  J   J K K  L    M   M N  NN O   O P     Q  Q   R R       S   TT   U   U   V V    W W W   X X    Y    Z   
A  A BBBB   CCC DDD  EEEE F     GGG  H  H III  JJJ  K  K LLLL M   M N   N  OOO  P      QQ Q  R  RR SSSS    TT    UUU     V      W W   X   X   Y   ZZZZZ




 11   22  333  4  4 5555   6   77777  888   9999  000       //!!!  @@@   # #  %   %%  ^^   &&    ((  ))                                                
111  2  2    3 4  4 5     6       7  8   8 9   9 0  00     // !!! @   @ #####    %%  ^  ^ &  &  ((    ))                                              
 11    2   33  4444 555  6666    7    888   9999 0 0 0    //  !!! @  @@  # #    %%         &&& &((    ))                                         
 11   2      3    4    5 6   6   7   8   8    9  00  0   //       @     #####  %%         & & & ((    ))                                              
11l1 2222 333     4 555   666    7    888    9    000   //    !!!  @@@   # #  %%   %       &&&&  ((  ))   ____
```

For other characters, the [equivalent produced by this generator](http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php) using the 'Alphabet' font will be acceptable.   If the output generated by the tool is more than 5 characters tall, use the central 5 characters for output.

**Edit -** I've allowed the program to read its own source code to possibly open this question up to interesting answers.

Comment: You should precisely describe the "font" to be used, otherwise you'll have lots of people deciding separately whether W needs to be 6 or 5 or fewer columns wide, etc.

Comment: Commonly these types of problems forbid a program from reading its own source code (or external resources and such). Is this the case here, and if so can you specify so in the problem.

Comment: Are spaces necessary, I don't see them in the example?

Comment: So we can no longer just use `*`?

Comment: edited for these questions- spaces existing in the code are necessary and can be as small as one bit wide. You can use any character in place of the alphanumerics used in the font.

Comment: @ThomasCleberg The `A` looks like it's missing a space on the first line (` AA ` would look better than the current `AA  `)

Comment: Ew... the `$` generated by the linked page is 7 lines tall instead of 5. :(

Comment: Does the middle 5 lines of that character seem like a reasonable solution?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me!

Comment: Edited to include these instructions.

Comment: Here's another odd one: underscore is four blank lines followed by two lines of four underscores (and no trailing space).

Comment: Let's call that one 4 underscores at the bottom of a 5x4 block. I will edit it into the description when at a computer.

Comment: No- boring loopholes are boring.

Comment: Also, specifically has to have at least one visible character in the output as specified.

Comment: I didn't (and still don't) see the 1 in the output. Please note that spaces are significant characters in the output and must be represented as well :)  Interesting loopholes are interesting!

Comment: Ah, I see it now. This is a valid answer once the spaces involved are represented in the output (by an at-least 1w,5h set of spaces per space in the source), and likely close to an optimal solution, though ^ and L use fewer characters in the output. White space is not included in the score calculation, but is required in the output.

Comment: Whitespace's winning

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 2142 bytes

Should work, it's pretty confusing to read the output.

```
n=["","","","",""]
t=["EEEE","E  E","EEE ","E   "," EE "," E "," EEE ","E   E","E    ","  EE  ","EEEE "," EEEE","   ","EEE","     ","EE EE","    "]
e=[[t[4],t[1],t[0],t[1],t[1]],[t[2],t[1],t[1],t[1],t[2]],[t[0],t[3],t[2],t[3],t[0]],[t[0],t[3],t[2],t[3],t[3]],[t[6],t[8],"E  EE",t[7],t[6]],["EEE",t[5],t[5],t[5],"EEE"],[t[3],t[3],t[3],t[3],t[0]],[t[7],"EE  E","E E E","E  EE",t[7]],[t[6],t[7],t[7],t[7],t[6]],[t[10],t[7],t[10],t[8],t[8]],[t[10],t[7],t[10],"E E  ","E  EE"],[t[6],"E    ",t[6],"    E",t[6]],["E"*6,t[9],t[9],t[9],t[9]],[t[4],t[2],t[4],t[4],t[0]],[t[4],t[1],"  E "," E  ",t[0]],[t[2],"   E",t[4],"   E",t[2]],[t[1],t[1],t[0],"   E","   E"],[t[0],t[3],t[2],"   E",t[2]],["  E  "," E   ",t[10],t[7],t[6]],["EEEEE","   E ","  E  ","  E  ","  E  "],[t[6],t[7],t[6],t[7],t[6]],[t[11],t[7],t[11],"   E ","  E  "],[t[6],"E  EE","E E E","EE  E",t[6]],["EE    "," EE   ","  EE  ","   EE ","    EE"],[t[12],t[13],t[12],t[13],t[12]],[t[0],"EE  ","EE  ","EE  ",t[0]],[t[0],"  EE","  EE","  EE",t[0]],[t[15],t[15],t[14],t[14],t[14]],["  ","  ","  ","  ","EE"],[" EE","EE ","EE ","EE "," EE"],["EE "," EE"," EE"," EE","EE "],[t[12],t[5],t[13],t[5],t[12]],[t[16],t[16],t[16],t[16],t[0]],["  ","EE","  ","EE","  "],["  ","EE","  ","EE"," E"]]
def s(i):
 if i==" ":r()
 if i=="a":g(e[0])
 if i=="d":g(e[1])
 if i=="e"or i=="E":g(e[2])
 if i=="f":g(e[3])
 if i=="g":g(e[4])
 if i=="i":g(e[5])
 if i=="l":g(e[6])
 if i=="n":g(e[7])
 if i=="o":g(e[8])
 if i=="p":g(e[9])
 if i=="r":g(e[10])
 if i=="s":g(e[11])
 if i=="t":g(e[12])
 if i=="1":g(e[13])
 if i=="2":g(e[14])
 if i=="3":g(e[15])
 if i=="4":g(e[16])
 if i=="5":g(e[17])
 if i=="6":g(e[18])
 if i=="7":g(e[19])
 if i=="8":g(e[20])
 if i=="9":g(e[21])
 if i=="0":g(e[22])
 if i=="\\":g(e[23])
 if i=="=":g(e[24])
 if i=="[":g(e[25])
 if i=="]":g(e[26])
 if i=="\"":g(e[27])
 if i==",":g(e[28])
 if i=="(":g(e[29])
 if i==")":g(e[30])
 if i=="+":g(e[31])
 if i=="_":g(e[32])
 if i==":":g(e[33])
 if i==";":g(e[34])
 r()
def g(p):
 for i in range(5):n[i]+=p[i]
def r():g([" "," "," "," "," "])
for l in open(__file__).read().split("\n"):
 for i in l:s(i)
 print"\n".join(n);n=["","","","",""]
```

Output is 47965 bytes.

Can probably be golfed a lot more.

The code above uses half of the alphabet, all numbers and some symbols/special characters. I used the letter `E` for the output.

The characters are a list of five strings, each for one line. Also, to save a few bytes, there's a list with common lines (`"EEEE"`, `"E  E"`, etc.)

The `,` has two lines, and one of them is below most characters, so I only included the upper one (same for underscore).

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 266

**34721 bytes code, 177815 total bytes of output, 266 bytes of which are non-whitespace.**

```pl
eval'                                                                                                                  	                                                                                                	                                                                                                                        	                               	                                                                                                                	                                                                                                                          	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                                                                	                                                                	                               	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                                                                                              	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                               	                                                                  	                                                                  	                                                                  	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                                                                             	                               	                               	                               	                                                                             	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                               	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                   	                                   	                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                     	                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                               	         	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                                                                	                               	                               	                                                                	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                                                                                              	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                                                            	                                                            	                                                            	                               	                               	                                                                                                                             	                               	                                                                                                                             	                               	                                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                               	                               	                                          	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                             	                                                                             	                               	                               	                                                                             	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                   	                               	                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                     	                               	                               	                                     	                               	                               	                               	                                      	                                      	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                 	         	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                                                                	                                                                	                                                                	                                                                	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                              	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                                                             	                               	                                                                                                                             	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                          	                                          	                                          	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                                                                       	                                                                       	                                                                       	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                               	                                                                             	                               	                                                                             	                               	                                                                             	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                                                                       	                                                                       	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                   	                                   	                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                     	                                     	                                     	                               	                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                               	         	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                               	                                                                	                               	                               	                                                                	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                              	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                            	                                                            	                                                            	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                          	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                             	                               	                               	                                                                             	                                                                             	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                               	                                   	                               	                                   	                               	                                     	                               	                                     	                               	                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                                                                      	                               	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	         	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                	                               	                               	                                                                	                               	                                                                           	                                                                           	                                                                           	                                                                           	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                              	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                                                                                  	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                  	                                                                  	                                                                  	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                                                                           	                                                                           	                                                                           	                                                                           	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                                                                             	                               	                               	                               	                                                                             	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                                   	                                                                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                               	                                                                       	                               	                                   	                                   	                                   	                                   	                               	                               	                               	                                     	                                     	                                     	                                     	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                               	                                                                      	                                                                      	                                                                      	                               	                               	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                                                                    	                               	                                                                                 	                               	                               	                                                                                 	                                                                                 	                                                                                                                            	                                                            	                                                                                                                             	                                                                                                                  	                                              	                                                                                              	                                              	                                   	                                 	                                                                                                                       	                                                  	                                                    	                                                   	                                                 	                                                	                                              	                                                                                                      	                                                                                                    	                                                                                                                 	         	'=~s' +\t'chr length$&'ger
```

Based on the [scoring confirmed by @Thomas Cleberg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49850#comment217559_49850), something like this is likely optimal, but feels a little cheaty. This encodes a program that prints the desired output as space and tab characters, which are replaced with the result of running `ord` on the length of each run (spaces, terminated by a tab). To cater for this in the output, each tab is represented with two spaces (over the five lines) and all spaces are shown as described above.

TIO limits the output to 128KiB so you can't see it all there, but if you run this program locally, it should work as expected. Something like:

```sh
perl -M5.010 metascii-code-golf.pl > metascii-code-golf.txt
```

and view `metascii-code-golf.txt` in a text editor with word-wrap disabled.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Z1BTsNADEXXvkUWiCwQqCy65AjcgA1CUYsUtVVbseTohDNQEdvfft1OYns8tseeH09P03neLsv09T6Pg/vP5BncytjKqXpl1s2IWEqrjB7POev1LSaTXkVsxDL7oehkGXc3lhokMfO@EdJSWKzFG7naZu8f7aBI8kcVmNtPtXKoJNJokYmoiaCpT5ME6O9yeD3jo1NLodd29RFbDESonvy3OVNwFZAmnVnnj6scNkTlCTkWLsNk876c7qsPpGuwSYnAYiiWJBFsS2drAXdKVsBrQSvKmVWSMzu@h8pBk93z//lkoOEDemhwkTzsaBEA60VxZYkBlcJTAKSOshj9ThjS87WtHPX5qLe1dHTi4DQxjzaIOl3Ahqp0@Gyr3yZFY45UWZzZ4YFa4sQofP4BcEMmcoscdMjESiTiYwR40i3qE7d1aIFsFm0i0dQVrS94TovTkLrtLVg1S4J1dI1rBeXowBGUQ6zYbXnDVsq5VSm9dGsCQIf6cqh0m9SjQuDKJGbD5EM9o@aasw4WWmJWHL83owUEwLjW8kOSccbDrJK/WGlVu@SNh0qIBZkkVe76XgGkFOciTa66SZIKg84EBCLaOOKfAsspGJTJjKiJ8m61PsxzX1QTz9LkpLG0a25OBmIu75i25bmysUBbs/Hl@zIOD2/X8WN/HubpsLvu7@7H3XRelp/j6fp5PFyWx9ft0@Z58ws)

Comment: Better late than never! Nevertheless, very great answer!

Comment: @Dada thanks! I'm hoping to get the output down further as I've really enjoyed this challenge. Sad I missed it when it was first posted, but glad I caught it when it was updated recently!